# Haskell Check if only element satisfies a given condition

Tags: haskell

I am working on a assignment that checks if there is only a single element that satisfies a given condition, I've thought about passing map to get a list of Boolean values and then counting if it has value 1 if it does I return True if not then I return False.

```
single :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
single p [] = False
single p a = map p a
let c = single p a
single count True c = if k == 1
    then True 
    else False
```

Which I have count that is:

```
count :: (Num a, Eq b) => b -> [b] -> a
count _ [] = 0
count x list = sum $ map (const 1) $ filter (== x) list
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution contains some errors. For example the second parameter of single is a list, so `single count True c` makes no sense. You can work with:

```
single :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
single p a = count True (map p a) == 1
```

but is not very efficient. `filter p a` will produce a list with the same length as `filter (== True) (map p a)`, and does not require first mapping and then filtering. Furthermore by counting the number of items that satisfy the condition, you will enumerate over the *entire list*, even if you already found two items that match, and you thus know that it can no longer contain exactly one item that matches.

You can work with `filter` and pattern match on an list with exactly one item, and let this return `True`, for the two other cases (the empty list, and a list with two or more items), we return `False`, so:

```
single :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
single p a = case filter p a of
    [_] -> True
    _ -> False
```

This will prevent enumerating over the entire list if it can find two items that satisfy the given condition.

Comment: `filter (== True) (map p a)` is equivalent to `filter p a` only in the very specific situation where you care only about the list's length, and not its values.

Comment: @amalloy: ah yes, rewrote this to "with the same length as ...".